# Angularjs Routing resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say in 90-95% of my routes I need to check if user is in (let's say jail).
Then, I'm currently doing something like:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            injail: function(jailservice){
                return jailservice.injail();
        }
    }
})
```

Do I really need to do this resolve on each route? (the routes are in different folders, each route file contains route for a specific module).

Is it something better I can do than call the resolve injail on every route?

Answer (score 3):

A few options.

**Option 1 - use parent state with resolve**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        resolve:{
            resA: function () {}
        }
    })
    .state('parent.child', {
        // resA from parent state available to all child states
        controller: function (resA) {}
    });
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534015/angular-ui-router-resolve-for-parent-state)

**Option 2 - external resolve functions (less duplicated code)**

Declaration:

```
resolve: {
    myResolve: myResolve
}
```

If using ES2015, you can shorten it to `resolve: {myResolve}` ([see enhanced object literals](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals))

**Definition (in a separate file containing all resolves):**

```
myResolve.$inject = ['myService'];
function myResolve(myService) {
    return myService.getStuff();
}
```

[More info](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

**EDIT - example using your code:**
In your routes declaration, change resolve to: `resolve: {injail: injailResolve}`

In separate file, the definition:

```
injailResolve.$inject = ['jailservice'];
function injailResolve(jailservice) {
    return jailservice.injail();
}
```

Comment: Think so, but it will require you to change the structure of your routes, can be quite some work... Option 2 is more straightforward.

Comment: how would the myservice injection look like? could you provide an example of that file too?

Comment: It's just a flat JS file with each resolve defined as above (see Definition). The functions are global so make sure to make them unique. The `$inject` bit will be used by angular at run-time to inject the actual service.

Comment: a flat js file With for example one of them are like:  injail: function(jailservice){
                return jailservice.injail();
        }?

Comment: or is it a acual factory/service im injecting?